# What can procs and lambdas do that functions can't in ruby

Tags: ruby, functions, lambda

I've been working in Ruby for the last couple weeks, and I've come to the subject of procs, lambdas and blocks.  After reading a fair share of examples from a variety of sources, I don't how they're much different from small, specialized functions.  It's entirely possible that the examples I've read aren't showing the power behind procs and lambdas.

```
def zero_function(x)
    x = x.to_s
   if x.length == 1
    return x = "0" + x
   else
    return x
   end
end

zero_lambda = lambda {|x|
  x = x.to_s
   if x.length == 1
    return x = "0" + x
   else
    return x
   end
}

zero_proc = Proc.new {|x|
  x = x.to_s
   if x.length == 1
    puts x = "0" + x
   else
    puts x
   end
}


puts zero_function(4)
puts zero_lambda.call(3)
zero_proc.call(2)
```

This function, proc, and lambda do the exact same thing, just slightly different.  Is there any reason to choose one over another?

Comment: I don't know ruby or what a "proc" is, but often times in languages a lambda's purpose is to act more as a variable (closure) than as a method, and can be passed around as such. Can a plain function in ruby be passed around like a variable?

Comment: @JimmyHoffa In ruby you can get a Method-object with `Object#method`. The Method object acts as a closure in obj’s object instance, so instance variables and the value of self remain available.

Comment: @knut How is that implemented though? Does it return a `Method-object` as its own object, or as a `proc`?

Comment: @KChaloux It's an own [Method-object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Method.html). The Method-class is inheriting from [Proc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html). But I'm no expert for this, that's why I am curious on other answers for this question ;)

Comment: You can make currying with lambdas and get another lambda, ie composition of functions.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa: a `Proc` *is* Ruby's name for a "plain function" as you call it. Except Ruby doesn't call it "function", because a function by definition cannot have side-effects, and Ruby is not a pure language, so it is called `Proc` (short for "procedure" instead).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, what do you mean by "functions"? Proc and lambda *are* "functions" -- and they evaluate to a function object, which could be assigned to a variable or used in any other expression. There is no other way to define a non-method "function" in Ruby.

`def`, by contrast, defines a *method* in the current module (you are always inside some module, either explicitly or implicitly). A method is obviously different from a bare function because a method implicitly has access to `self` and the instance variables of `self`.

More importantly, Proc and lambda are closures -- they capture local variables from the enclosing scope where they were created, and you can use those variables inside the closure. This allows function objects to hold state.

By contrast, defining a method inside another method definition will not give access to the local variables in the outer method body. So it's the same as if you moved the inner definition outside, except that the method defined by the inner `def` will only exist after the method defined by the outer `def` is run.

Answer (score 0):

Good question! I'm curious on the answers.

One difference I know:

You get no error with this call:

```
zero_proc.call()
```

But you get a `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)`-error with the following calls:

```
puts zero_function()
puts zero_lambda.call()
```

Methods and lambdas check the number of parameters, Proc-objects don't, the use `nil` if there are missing parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The other big difference between procs, methods and lambdas is how they deal with break and return.

Basically, a return in a Proc will jump out of any enclosing method as well, and a return from a lambda will only exit the lambda.

A break from a Proc tries to break out of an enclosing iteration (if there's no iteration, you'll get an error), while a break from a lambda is just like a return.

More details here: http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/ruby-procs-and-lambdas-and-the-difference-between-them/